# How to create 3D globe images highlighting a specific country or 2D country map with capital?

Tags: cartography, 3d, rendering, globe, 2d

I am building an Anki flashcard set that should contain country flags, names and (ideally) a 3D globe with the country outlined, as can be seen on [Wikipedia](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Grey-green_orthographic_projections_maps).

I've already completed the part that extracts all the information from the Wikipedia page listing all countries, and I've written a tool that extracts country outlines from an SVG file that has the shapes for all countries and renders them into a bitmap.

Unfortunately, the polygon outlines in this SVG file are extremely crude, so it makes little sense to use them for the cards. Additionally, I'd prefer beautiful rendered globes with the countries highlighted as in the Wikipedia examples, or a flat map with cities (would be cool to have both maybe).

I'd be happy to have a simple method to download/create/extract globe images with whatever tool necessary, I'd prefer something that can be integrated into a project where the map is queried using [ISO-3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1) codes. So:

- Is there a page where maps could be downloaded using the ISO code? I tried using the Wikipedia images but they are not named in a fashion that makes it easy to download them using the ISO code.
- Could this be achieved using QGIS? Possibly using a script?
- Can this be achieved using LaTeX? I remember that I have seen some examples rendering a globe with it, but I cannot find the page anymore.

Comment: I found a solution yesterday and will post how I did it when I have a working program, which can take some time as this is only a side project.

Comment: Hows your side project coming along?

Comment: It is actually frozen since more urgent tasks (= kids) came along and ate up all my spare time :) As fas as I can remember I got to rendering country outlines, but couldn't integrate them into the flash cards.